# Responsive Line next to a header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a response line next to a heading [image]

Picture above is from a pdf not the site

I tried using a Div with a border bottom but its out of place because its a border it sits lower, I then tried using a `<hr` And The same thing it doesnt align properly There are one's at the bottom center ect.

How do I achieve something of the sorts without having to set responsive stylings every few pixel's.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="we-are">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2>We are.</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 line-right">
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.line-right hr{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px #BFE2CA solid;
    }
```

My result:

[image]

I do realize I can ofcourse do something like
`marign-top:50px`
But it wont be very responsive

Comment: What is a "response line"? Will this eventually change to something like an `<input>`? In that case, it will change the question and any answers.

Comment: Typo on my part Meant to say Responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach using *pseudo-elements*

Here your HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="we-are">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="parent">
                    <h2>We are.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

And here your CSS, where the line is made by the _pseudo-element after:

```
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent:after{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: calc(100% + 20px);
    width: 500px; /* Or whatever you need, e.g. width: calc(100vw - 200px); */
    height: 5px;
    background: #BFE2CA;
}
```

If you want to have the line vertically aligned just change your CSS accordingly (remove bottom and add top):

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Here's a working live Codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/dyYGxYY

Comment: I would just have to set the width for every screen size then right? But yes this could. potentially work, Will give it a try and get back to u

Comment: @Azurry you can make something pretty flexible like: width: calc(100vw - 200px); Let me know

Comment: Hmm same issue, its lower then the element next to it I'd have to set a bottom value

Comment: @Azurry It's not an issue, it because of height/line-height of the sibling element, just change it to: bottom: 4px; You don't need to change the bottom value for all the size

Comment: Hmm your actually right thats crazy, First time seeing the calc for width and such I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the assistance, If you had to center this would u just adjust the bottom value again right?

Comment: @Azurry you mean vertically center? Cause in that case I can suggest you a flexible unique technique!

Comment: Yes vertically, issue is they have a few at the bottom a few at the center and such, so its changing every so element

Comment: @Azurry Update code in the answer and in the codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/dyYGxYY

Comment: Thanks for the help Alessio!

Answer (score 0):

Yous should use something like dynamic when the font or the screen varies, you have to set the line to the period symbol first and then even if you increase/decrease the font that shouldn't change the line.

you can try something like this. you can try to change the font and you see the line sticks to the same position and you just have to increase the height of the line based on font.

[Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/b2txyv4r/34/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:3em; /* change the size and see the difference */
}

.parent:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: calc(100% + 20px);
  width: 500px;
    /* height is the only thing you have to change irrespective of the font. */
  height: 5px;
  background: #BFE2CA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="we-are">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="parent">
        <h2>We are.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```